# Reading timestamp from database is 4 hours later than GMT time. But was stored as GMT

Tags: java, database, timestamp

My code says it all.  Simple question, but I can't seem to figure out how to read this timestamp back correctly:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

//later, this code gets executed, and the "now" calendar object is the value:
insert into mytable (mydate) values(?)
```

When I read from this table, I get back a timestamp.  Why is the timestamp is 4 hours later?

Of course, that's the offset from GMT from where I live, but a timestamp is just a number. I thought that since my calendar is in GMT zone, its timestamp is inserted as GMT time.

```
Timestamp mydate = rs.getTimestamp("mydate");
```

I see that Timestamp wraps the Date object. The date object it wraps after I read it from the database is zoned in my timezone (not GMT). I'm not sure how to convert this back to GMT or if there's a way to read it directly as GMT.

Comment: you didn't provide the code on how you read the timestamp, and I'm guessing that when you read it, it is converted to your time zone

Comment: Hi Tima, I updated the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found what I needed:

```
java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Timestamp mydate = rs.getTimestamp("mydate", cal);
```